# How to use Karate framework for a SOAP GET api call?

Tags: soap, karate, karate-call-single

How to use Karate framework for a SOAP GET api call?

I am trying to look for an example of KARATE framework to make a GET SOAP api call. Feature file and the step definitions.

(I do not have so much write, this is not allowing me to post unless I type so much. 220 characters are required in body)